# Run time error 424 .. object required

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am getting this error in Microsoft Access:

> runtime error 424 object required

And below is the VBA code that I have used on the backend of a button:

VBA Code

```
Private Sub Command87_Click()
If Me.phase <> "" Then
    Me.lst_caseItems.RowSource = " " & _
        "SELECT tbl_master.fld_masterID, " & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterActionNo AS ActionNumber, " & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterStudyActionNo AS StudyActionNo, tbl_master.fld_masterIssuedTo," & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterRev AS Rev, tbl_phases.fld_phase AS Phase, tbl_studies.fld_study AS Study, " & _
        "FROM ((tbl_master LEFT JOIN tbl_studies ON tbl_master.fld_studyID = ' " & tbl_studies.fld_studyID & " ') LEFT JOIN tbl_phases ON tbl_master.fld_phaseID = ' " & tbl_phases.fld_phaseID & " ') LEFT JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_master.fld_locationID = ' " & tbl_locations.fld_locationID & " ';"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that `phase` variable and `lst_caseItems`are available in the context of the `Command87_Click()`? Use debugger breakpoints to see what is available while code is executed. P.S.: _backend_ and _codebehind_ are different terms, in this case it's codebehind. P.P.S.: 87 buttons? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, VBA thinks `tbl_studies.fld_studyID` is a variable hence asking for an object.

With your current code;

```
' " & tbl_studies.fld_studyID & " '
```

The `"` CLOSES the SQL statement, then your ampersand `tbl_studies` or etc tells VBA to add in the value of the variable `tbl_studies.fld_studyID` then the ampersand followed by `"` reopens the SQL statement within VBA (so on compile all flows as necessary). As you have no variable named `studyID` it looks like this is the cause of your object required.

To get around this, you either need to assign a variable to the ID you want (such as `dim X as long` then `x = studyIDyouwanthere`) or write your query correctly so it links to the studies table with field `studyID`. Looking at it more closely it looks like you just need to write the query properly in the VBA window so it's syntactically correct (in VBA's interpretation) try the following;

```
Private Sub Command87_Click()
If Me.phase <> "" Then
    Me.lst_caseItems.RowSource = " " & _
        "SELECT tbl_master.fld_masterID, " & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterActionNo AS ActionNumber, " & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterStudyActionNo AS StudyActionNo, tbl_master.fld_masterIssuedTo," & _
            "tbl_master.fld_masterRev AS Rev, tbl_phases.fld_phase AS Phase, tbl_studies.fld_study AS Study, " & _
        "FROM ((tbl_master LEFT JOIN tbl_studies ON tbl_master.fld_studyID = tbl_studies.fld_studyID) LEFT JOIN tbl_phases ON tbl_master.fld_phaseID = tbl_phases.fld_phaseID ) LEFT JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_master.fld_locationID =  tbl_locations.fld_locationID;"
End If
End Sub
```

When you are joining on queries in VBA you don't join based on the values of variables, you'll only be using them for your `select` part or `having`/`where`/`group BY` not on the joins.

Comment: Heay mark ... using your code there is no error but when I run code I do not get any values passed to me.lst_CaseItems.RowSource ... kindly see that this is happening on the click event of a button so is the vba sql allowed on button click in access

Comment: I think as it about access-vba, `tbl_studies.fld_studyID` is a field in `tbl_studies` table ;).

Comment: you may need to add a me.lst_caseItems.refresh after you set the rowsource Zeeshan